# AuthComponent::user('id') not returning correct data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

In my AppModel, I have a beforeSave function:

```
    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['created'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['created'] = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
            $this->data[$this->alias]['modified'] = $this->data[$this->alias]['created'];
        } else {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['modified'] = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
        }
        $this->data[$this->alias]['modified_by'] = AuthComponent::user('id');

        return true;
    }
```

It's a simple function that just records the created and modified dates, and sets a field modified_by to the id of the currently logged in user. Or at least that's what it's supposed to do, everything works except getting the id of the currently logged in user, and I can't figure out why, because as far as I can tell in the documentation, that's exactly how it should be called.

Comment: Have you tried to dump the value returned by `AuthComponent::user('id')`? Does it actually return an id? And if that's the case, are you maybe passing a [field list](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array) to your `Model::save*()` call?

Comment: 0 keeps getting entered into the database for the modified_by field. And this is my call to save, $this->News->Save($this->request->data['News'])

Comment: So does `AuthComponent::user('id')` actually return `0`? If not, have you checked the SQL debug output, what does the generated `INSERT/UPDATE` query look like?

Comment: Apparently it's not entering anything. There's no field modified_by in the query, and thus no value either. But I still am not understanding why.

Comment: Just check the datatype of `modified_by` in your table may be the size  is small.

Comment: It's not too small, it's an int(10) unsigned, should be working fine.

Comment: Have you added the `modified_by` column after the application was already created? Does it show up in in the schema (`$this->News->schema()`)? Even if it does, try clearing the model cache (`/app/tmp/cache/models/`). If that also doesn't help, then I'm afraid I can't really help you any further, I'm already just shooting in the dark here. Maybe if you post some more code, the rest of the model, possible parent models that might modify the data, your controller...

Comment: @ndm I figured out the problem and added the answer below, thanks for taking the time to help me debug though, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my issue, and I feel a little dumb because of it, but thought I would add it here in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

In my News model, I was also calling the beforeSave function as well, but I forgot a line in it, namely `parent::beforeSave();`. How the date stuff in the beforeSave function was working, I don't know, but this fixed my problem of part of the beforeSave function not working.

Thanks for everyone's help in this matter, it's appreciated.

Comment: I was about to ask this as I've just realized that the code is in the `AppModel` (should have read the question more carefully)... fyi, CakePHP [**automatically updates `modified` and `created` columns**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#using-created-and-modified) properly in case they are `datetime default null` columns.

Comment: @ndm So, you're saying I can remove the code that does that? That's cool, I didn't know that. Thanks for that tidbit.

Answer (score 0):

why not grab your user id from

CakeSession::read( 'Auth.User.Id ) ?

Comment: Because this would stop working in case the `AuthComponent` implementation or the session key settings changes, because it doesn't work with stateless authentication, and assuming it would access the desired value it would make no difference to the actual problem at all.

Comment: even if the implementation changes, i suppose the value would still be stored in Auth.User cos it makes sense to be there, now or later. if it can access the desired value, what other underlying problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: No matter if it makes sense or not, one shouldn't rely on internals, that's why there is abstracted access via the `AuthComponent` API. And _I_ am not trying to solve anything, I'm not the OP, I'm just trying help him solve his problem, and for that problem it would make no difference whether the value he's trying to store is fetched via the `AuthComponent` API or directly via the `CakeSession` API (assuming the latter would access the same value).

Comment: @ndm you are right, one shouldn't rely on internals. i will dig a bit deeper to understand why they put it in a session if you can access it from AuthComponent app wide(right?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set user id in AppControlle::beforeFiler() method instead of AppModel

```
$this->data[$this->modelClass]['modified_by'] = $this->Auth->User('id');
```